# No such file or directory when install civiCRM

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

i try to install civiCRM on my Drupal 9 local website.
I use Mamp 5.5 on Mac.

I follow all install information and now I'm hold on this situation:

% cv core:install --db="mysql://civicrm_user:myuser@localhost:3306/mydb" --lang=it_IT -vv

```
Box Requirements Checker
========================

> Using PHP 7.4.10
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini

> Checking Box requirements:
  .....

                                                                                
 [OK] Your system is ready to run the application.                              
                                           
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  
                                                    

Exception trace:
 () at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:150
 PDO->__construct() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:150
 Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::open() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php:380
 Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php:169
 Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php:79
 Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:171
 Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php:212
 Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php:62
 Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:171
 Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:546
 Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:891
 Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() at /Users/cmazzarago/Local_Sites/FondazionePico/fondazione_pico/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:470
 Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/CmsBootstrap.php:251
 Civi\Cv\CmsBootstrap->bootDrupal8() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/CmsBootstrap.php:139
 Civi\Cv\CmsBootstrap->bootCms() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Util/BootTrait.php:130
 Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->_boot_cms_only() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Util/SetupCommandTrait.php:54
 Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->bootSetupSubsystem() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Command/CoreInstallCommand.php:56
 Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:850
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Application.php:46
 Civi\Cv\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:124
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Application.php:15
 Civi\Cv\Application::main() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/bin/cv:27
 require() at /usr/local/bin/cv:14

core:install [--settings-path [SETTINGS-PATH]] [--setup-path [SETUP-PATH]] [--src-path [SRC-PATH]] [--plugin-path [PLUGIN-PATH]] [--cms-base-url [CMS-BASE-URL]] [--lang [LANG]] [--comp [COMP]] [--ext [EXT]] [--db [DB]] [-m|--model [MODEL]] [-A|--abort] [-K|--keep] [-f|--force] [--debug-event [DEBUG-EVENT]] [--debug-model] [--level LEVEL] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER]
```

any suggestion ???
i'm very sad :((

thanks a lot
claudio.

Answer (score 0):

Your --db setting might be wrong. It's not civicrm_user:myuser, it should be myuser:mypass. Also on some systems "localhost" doesn't work and you need to use `127.0.0.1`, e.g.

`--db="mysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb"`

But also you don't need --db unless you need to install civi in a separate database from drupal. It will guess your drupal database.

Also you usually need to specify --cms-base-url, since otherwise it might think your website is literally `http://default`.

Comment: Hi Demerito, i try without --db initially but e received the same error, so next i try with --db parameter.
my DB is ok and the web site works properly, so i don't understand why i have this issue :(

Comment: Did drupal install ok? I mean are you able to visit the drupal site and it works?

Comment: Yes web site work properly (it's a new installation of Drupal). any suggestion ?  thanks

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? - have updated answer.

Comment: Hi, i tried with --cms-base-url parameter but i received the same error.
Now i tried with another Drupal installation on my local with Acquia Dev Desktop and now i have this error: 
[Drupal\Core\Database\ConnectionNotDefinedException]       
  The specified database connection is not defined: default  

thai is similar to the previous.

Comment: Where to use 127.0.0.1 instead "localhost" ?

Comment: Have updated answer to give full example for --db.

Comment: i tried with your suggestion but nothing. Same error. I try many many combination of installation string. :(